# Объясните поведение функции emit() в mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, функции

например бд

```
var post={
      author:"Ivanov",
      text:"...",
      old:35,
      discription:{
         position:"manager",
         salary:150000
      }
    };
var map=function(){
    emit(this.author,this.disription);
};
//далее в функциии reduce можно можно работать с полями author и disription более чем понятно
var reduce=function(key,values){};
// но когда вот так
var map=function () {
    emit(this.author,{count:1,disription:this.disription});// что значит count:1 ? в чем смысл 1
};
//или вот так
var map=function () {
    emit(this.old,1);
}
// я не понимаю
```

Comment: приведите полный код `mapReduce`. `map` нагенерил вам объектов ключ-значение, а что с ними дальше происходит решает `reduce`. там и надо логику смотреть зачем count:1 и т.д.  
`emit(this.old, 1)` видимо для подсчета авторов по возрастам, дальше `Array.sum(values)` в reduce и будет статистика по возрастам - количество авторов определенного возраста.  
вполне наглядная картинка в [доках](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: а тогда почему вот здесь-> http://cookbook.mongodb.org/index.html в в первом уроке автор передает в функцию emit(this.tags[index],1) число 1 затем в reduce(key,value) используется цикл for. Ведь for используется для переборки свойства типа ключ:значение.

Comment: emit(this.tags[index],1) для каждого тэга из списка тегов создает объект. после map будет:

    {"MongoDB":[1,1,1,1,1...]}, {"Map/Reduce":[1,1,1...]}, {"Recipe":[1,1...]}

дальше reduce для каждого объекта пройдется по этому списку значений и просуммирует единички для одинаковых ключей. на выходе будет сгенерирована коллекция (в терминах mongo).

Comment: а как определяется количество этих единичек для каждого объекта?

Comment: их будет столько, сколько раз встречался данный тег в списке тэгов в изначальной коллекции.

Answer (score 1):

вообщем вот так получается

```
{
    "title" : "A blog post",
    "author" : "Kristina",
    "content" : "...",
    "tags" : ["MongoDB", "Map/Reduce", "Recipe"]
}
```

вбиваем функции map и reduce в консоль вызываем

```
db.blog.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:"test_reduce"})
db.test_reduce.find()
```

получаем:

```
 { "_id" : "Map/Reduce", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "MongoDB", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Recipe", "value" : 1 }
```

обновляем:

```
db.blog.update({author:"Kristina"},{$push:{tags:"MongoDB"}})
db.blog.update({author:"Kristina"},{$push:{tags:"MongoDB"}})
db.blog.update({author:"Kristina"},{$push:{tags:"MongoDB"}})
```

вызываем `db.test_reduce.find()`

```
{ "_id" : "Map/Reduce", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "MongoDB", "value" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "Recipe", "value" : 1 }
```